# How do I create an arbitrary amount of Entry boxes in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating an app to handle all sorts of matrix math and I'm currently in the process of making the input for any n x n matrix into a grid of entry boxes. My current function makes the grid I am looking for but it's the same entry box over and over. I was wondering if there is any way to make them all unique(something like entry_0_0 , entry_n_n) when laying out an arbitrary amount of entries.

```
from numpy import *
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.title('Matrix')
num = StringVar()

def createGrid(r, c):

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            entry = Entry(master, textvariable=num, width=2)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
            j += 1
        i += 1

r = int(input('Enter Square Matrix Size: '))
c = r

createGrid(r, c)
```

Comment: You can use a list to track them. This will allow your to work with each one without having to create unique names.

Answer (score 1):

> but it's the same entry box over and over

No, it isn't.  Your entry boxes are unique but they *all* point to the same `StringVar` text variable and so will all show the same value.  Rather than a single `StringVar` you need a matrix of them, that matches your matrix of entries:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def createGrid(rows, columns):

    textMatrix = []

    for r in range(rows):
        textRow = []

        for c in range(columns):
            variable = StringVar()

            entry = Entry(master, textvariable=variable, width=2)
            entry.grid(row=r, column=c)

            textRow.append(variable)

        textMatrix.append(textRow)

    return textMatrix

columns = rows = int(input('Enter Square Matrix Size: '))

num = StringVar()

text_matrix = createGrid(rows, columns)

# Test that we can set all the matrix entries independently

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        text_matrix[r][c].set(r * columns + c)

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, you don't really need the `StringVar` here. You can get and set the values of entry widgets without it. Most of the time they end up being extra things you have to keep track of without providing any real value.